# Find the range of a

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry

> If the point $P(a^2,a)$ lies in the region corresponding to the acute
>   angles between the lines $2y=x$ and $4y=x$ then range of a is...

This would have been easy if the lines had constants and I can see the position of point with respect to origin but now both the lines pass through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
[image]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spMnP.png))

- What is the allowed region for points $P$, where $P = (a^2, a)$ for some real $a$?
- What is the equation of the curve where all $P$ reside on?
- Which $P$ are within the allowed region?
- What are the $a$ values of these points?

Comment: You'll need a broader range for $x$

Comment: The second crossing of the parabola with the green line

Comment: Thanks, I added the other intersection points. I hope OP will switch to equations at some time and then see multiple solutions.